# How can I add Jupyter notebook to Windows 10 default apps?

Tags: windows-10, file-association, jupyter-notebook

How can I add Jupyter Notebook to Windows 10 default apps? When I try to change default app for the file type `.ipynb` I can not see the Jupyter notebook in default apps list and there is no option to choose it.

How can I add it to the default apps list?

Answer (score 0):

Install `nbopen`: https://github.com/takluyver/nbopen

```
pip install nbopen
python -m nbopen.install_win
```

Now you can double-click on `*.ipynb` files.
Source - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47267932/associate-ipynb-files-with-jupyter-notebook-in-windows-10-anaconda

Comment: I saw it before and did what it says but didn't work!

Comment: @user3486308 open ```%ProgramData%``` and check if there is any folder named anacoda or anaconda3. If so, go to scripts folder and there will be jupyter-notebook.exe file.(I do have that exe). Now you just copy the path to exe, right click ipynb file, open with the exe path.

Answer (score 0):

Open Anaconda and then type:

```
pip install nbopen
python -m nbopen.install_win
```

Then select default python app for your notebook that will automatically opened in a notebook that matches your file extension.